# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bluej

I have been trying to write a Java program which converts the first letter of every word of a string into a capital letter. Right now it looks like this:

```
package strings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class small_cap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
        String st = sc.next();
        String str = " " + st;

        int j = 0; char chr = ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            j = i + 1;
            chr = str.charAt(j);
            if (chr == ' '){
                char a = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(j));
                str = str.replace(str.charAt(j), a);
            }
            else{
                char a = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(j));
                str = str.replace(str.charAt(j), a);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I keep on getting the error:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at small_cap.main(small_cap.java:19)
```

I don't really see any fault in the code. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: It seems pretty clear why you would get an index out of bounds exception, seeing as when i is length - 1, j is length, which is past the end of the string.

Comment: I also going to say that your logic looks very wrong. This is supposed to capitalize the first letter of each word in a sentence?

Comment: @c_dubs this program is supposed to capitalize the first letter of each word in a sentence and lowercase the other letters, just in case some of them are already capitalized. Now I see the mistake for which it was going of bounds. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking if the previous character was a space? (with a special case for the first character of the string) Something like: if i is 0, or charAt(i - 1) is space, then capitalize, else lowercase

Comment: @c_dubs that is what I was doing, but instead of i-1, I was using j, when j = i - 1. I just realised this was what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You were using Scanner.next() rather then Scanner.nextLine() which will read the whole sentence rather then single word.
2. You are adding extra space in String. Don't know the big reason behind that. It can be done without it.
3. Let say the Input is : "abc def" which will become " abc def" after adding extra space. Length of string will become : 7
4. Now for loop will iterate from 0 to 6. But on i = 6 it will try to alter the element on 7th position (since you are doing j=i+1) which will cause string index out of range error.
5. You are using String.Replace which will replace all matching characters irrespective of their position.

   import java.util.Scanner;

   ```
   public class small_cap {
       public static void main(String[] args) {

           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
           String st = sc.nextLine();
           String str = " " + st;

           int j = 0; char chr = ' ';

           for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++){
              j = i+1;

               chr = str.charAt(i);
               if (chr == ' '){
                   char a = Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(j));
                   str = str.substring(0,j)+a+str.substring(j+1);
               }
               else{
                   char a = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(j));
                   str = str.substring(0,j)+a+str.substring(j+1);
               }
           }
           System.out.println(str);
       }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        j = i + 1;
```

When `i` reaches the last valid index `length - 1`, `j` will be equal to `length`, which is out of bounds.

I don't really see the point of the `j` variable to begin with - did you mean to use `i` somewhere else inside the loop as well, or should you just make your loop start from 1? Or did you perhaps mean to check the previous character by doing `j = i - 1;` (in that case make sure you don't read before index 0)